# How could the BOE (barrel of oil equivalent) be measured?

Tags: energy, measurements, units

The barrel of oil equivalent was given as an example of gigajoule scale energy.

"The barrel of oil equivalent (BOE) is a unit of energy based on the approximate energy released by burning one barrel (42 U.S. gallons or 158.9873 litres) of crude oil."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_of_oil_equivalent

Now any idea how's that actually measured?

Comment: You burn a known quantity of oil in a calibrated calorimeter (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calorimeter)  and you measure the temperature rise inside. Real oil, of course, has varying chemical composition, so the exact value will vary somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious method is to burn a barrel of crude oil and measure how much energy is released.

The only slightly less obvious method is to burn a small amount of oil and measure how much energy is released, and then mathematically figure how much energy a whole barrel *would* release, as @CuriousOne points out.

The latter method is superior in both the economical and ecological senses.

Comment: How do you measure how much energy is released?

Comment: @mavavilj by measuring the temperature change when you burn the oil in a calorimeter. If this helps you, upvote CuriousOne's comment on your question, because he said it all there first.